# How do I reference Folder and Subfolder

Tags: powershell, automation, mailitem

How do I reference the email folder & subfolder?  In line 8 of my code, I am failing with olxEmailFolder and every other attempt to getting the folder.  Any thoughts?

```
#connect to outlook
$GetOutlook = New-Object -com "Outlook.Application"; 
$olName = $GetOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$olxEmailFolder = $olName.GetDefaultFolder('olFolderInbox')
$olxEmailFolder.Name
$olxEmailItem = $olxemailFolder.items
#show unread emails in inbox
$olxEmailItem | select olxEmailFolder, ReceivedByName, SentOnBehalfOfName, SentOn, Subject, Body | Format-Table -auto | Out-File "C:\results.txt"
#go through each subfolder and get name
$SubFolders = $olxEmailFolder.Folders
ForEach($Folder in $SubFolders)
{
   $Folder.Name
   $SubfolderItem = $Folder.Items
   $EmailCount = 1
#create status bar for each subfolder
   ForEach($Email in $SubfolderItem)
   {
     Do
     {
        Write-Progress -Activity "Checking folder" -status $Folder.Name -PercentComplete ($EmailCount/$Folder.Items.Count*100)
        $EmailCount++
     }
#show unread emails from subfolders
     While($EmailCount -le $Folders.Item.Count)
   }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing? This works fine for me.

Comment: I don't get an error, I just get nothing in my column.

Comment: Move your | Out-File "C:\results.txt" -append  to the end of the Write lines. All will be well. <>< <3 Hope

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go Copra:

```
#connect to outlook
$GetOutlook = New-Object -com "Outlook.Application"; 
$olName = $GetOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$olxEmailFolder = $olName.GetDefaultFolder(‘olFolderInbox’)
$olxEmailFolder.Name
$olxEmailItem = $olxemailFolder.items

#show unread emails in inbox
$olxEmailItem | select SentOn, SenderName, Subject, Body | Format-Table -auto | Out-File "C:\A_results.txt"

#go through each subfolder and get name
$SubFolders = $olxEmailFolder.Folders 

ForEach($Folder in $SubFolders)
{
   $Folder.Name | select $Folder.Name | Format-Table -auto | Out-File "C:\A_results.txt" -Append 
   $SubfolderItem = $Folder.Items
   $EmailCount = 1
#create status bar for each subfolder
   ForEach($Email in $SubfolderItem)
   {
     Do
     {
        Write-Progress -Activity "Checking folder" -status $Folder.Name -PercentComplete ($EmailCount/$Folder.Items.Count*100) 
        $EmailCount++
     }
#show unread emails from subfolders
     While($EmailCount -le $Folders.Item.Count)
   $Email | select SentOn, SenderName, Subject, Body | Format-Table -Auto | Out-File "C:\A_results.txt" -Append
   }
}
#connect to tasks
$olxTasksFolder = $olName.GetDefaultFolder(‘olFolderTasks’)
$olxTaskItems = $olxTasksFolder.items
$TaskCount = 1
#create task array
$TaskList = @()
ForEach($TaskItem in $olxTaskItems)
{
#create status bar for tasks
   Do
   {
     Write-Progress -Activity "Checking" -status "Tasks" -PercentComplete ($Taskcount/$olxTasksFolder.Items.count*100) | select $Taskcount, $olxTasksFolder.Items | Out-File "C:\D_results.txt"
     $TaskCount++
   }
#add each incomplete tash to array
   While($TaskCount -le $olxTaskFolder.Items.Count)
   If($TaskItem.Complete -eq $False)
   {
   $TaskList+=New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
   Subject=$TaskItem.Subject
   DateCreated=$TaskItem.CreationTime
   Percent=$TaskItem.PercentComplete
   Due=$TaskItem.DueDate
   }}
}
#show task array to screen
#$TaskList | Sort DueDate -descending | Format-Table -Auto
```